# How can you determine if a hypothesis (mathematical logic ones) is falsifiable enough to be "good"?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics

We had a group discussion and the prof gave us the following question and left. The problem is that I hardly understand the question.

> How can you determine if a hypothesis (in particular, mathematical logic ones) is falsifiable enough to be "good"?

Does anyone understand this question? Is it only me (to me, it is very ambiguous. What does "good" mean :( )? If you do, please enlighten me.

Comment: "falsifiable enough" ? In math log an hypotheses is an *assumption* or *premise* of an argument.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree with you that hypotheses is an assumption/premise.

Comment: First, your question is related to falsification and the theory of [critical rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_rationalism). This is a challenge to the way rational process works generally by adducing evidence to justify a belief. Rather, for an assertion to meaningful, it has to be able to be shown it is false; only if it can't be shown to be false, can we consider it true. But the question is now how does one show how an assertion, in this case a hypothesis, is true or false? Well this depends to some extent on your [theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth#Majo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to falsify an hypothesis in mathematics is to provide a counterexample.

One way to characterize an hypothesis as "good" is if there exists an effective method for finding a counterexample that could be used to falsify the hypothesis.  Here are the criteria for an effective method from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_method#Definition):

> A method is formally called effective for a class of problems when it satisfies these criteria:
>
> - It consists of a finite number of exact, finite instructions.
> - When it is applied to a problem from its class:
> - - It always finishes (terminates) after a finite number of steps.
> - - It always produces a correct answer.
> - In principle, it can be done by a human without any aids except writing materials.
> - Its instructions need only to be followed rigorously to succeed. In other words, it requires no ingenuity to succeed.

If the domain of the hypothesis is finite using the effective method on each member of the domain would result in a proof of the hypothesis if no counterexample were found.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, August 17). Effective method. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 13:50, September 4, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Effective_method&oldid=911289184